# Forge Design Automation Revit Workitem Arguments

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I'm following the Design Automation API v3 tutorial for Revit.

When doing a workitem post I'm a little unclear about the "rvtFile" and "result" arguments. Can the rvtFile url be in an aws bucket? Also what are the restrictions for the result website? It states that it needs to be a signed url, but can this just be another aws bucket? Or do I need to create a website? (Note: I've never done any web development. Everything I know i learned from this tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

Since Design Automation for Revit runs on cloud (and not your local machine), it needs a way to download your input files. You may put your files on any of the storage service providers (say Amazon S3) and provide direct download links to it. For Design Automation to have access to it, you will either need to make those files be public urls or keep them private and generate a signed url for it. When DA4R runs your workitem, the direct download urls provided in the workitem payload will be called to download your files to the worker machine.

Design Automation also does not store any of your result files. So, you will have to generate a signed url for uploading them to appropriate cloud location(s) (say a location in Amazon S3 bucket).

While Amazon S3 is just an example, there are several other storage providers. I also recommend reading Autodesk Forge's Data management APIs:
https://forge.autodesk.com/api/data-management-cover-page/

EDIT:
Useful links

Tutorials: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/

AU Class: https://www.autodesk.com/autodesk-university/class/Revit-Data-Forge-How-Can-Design-Automation-Revit-API-Help-Me-2018